# Как сложить числа находящиеся в строке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, float

```
numbers = "22.32 3.74 4.67 "
print(sum(numbers))
```

Как получить сумму чисел, находящихся в строке?

Comment: разложить строку на числа и получить сумму

Comment: разложить строку на числа ***по пробелу, элементы перевести во флоат*** и получить сумму

Comment: как это сделать? ошибка, если перевести в float

Comment: str_num = '22.32'; float_num = float(str_num) где там можно сделать ошибку?

Comment: @Jack начать читать учебник.

Comment: @Jack как вы разбаваете строку и переводите во флоат? добавьте в вопрос?

Comment: @Jack_oS попробуйте str_num = '22.32 3.74 4.67'

Comment: @Jack_oS и выйдет ошибка..

Comment: @Jack Для разбиения строки на части есть специальный метод `split`, сначала нужно воспользоваться им

Comment: Я и split делал. Все равно не могу сумму чисел найти. Обычно целые числа используют, а не с точкой..

Comment: @Jack Нет никакой разницы между целыми числами и числами с плавающей точкой, кроме того, что в одном случае преобразовывают в число через вызов `int`, а в другом через вызов `float`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разложите строку на числа (по пробелу), а элементы переведите во флоат:

```
str_num = "22.32      3.74     4.67               "
nums_sum = sum(float(x) for x in str_num.split())

>>> nums_sum
30.730000000000004
```

или

```
nums_sum = round(sum(float(x) for x in str_num.split()), 2)
```

чтоб округлить сразу ответ

Comment: можно чтобы после . было только две цифры (73)?

Comment: для всех чисел.

Comment: да, конечно: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Comment: спасибо, я разобрался

Answer (score 3):

Ладно, раз пошли подсказки в виде полного кода, то вот ещё *функциональный* вариант, плюс форматирование чтобы без лишних знаков:

```
numbers = "22.32 3.74 4.67 "
print(f'{sum(map(float, numbers.split())):g}')
```

Вывод:

```
30.73
```

Comment: здесь "функциональный" - из-за map(), функции высшего порядка?

Comment: @Jack_oS Я на самом деле в словаре точное значение не смотрел, но, вроде бы, "функциональные языки" - это где всё делается через вызов функций, никаких условных конструкций, циклов и т.д. - одни только функции :)  Вот и в питоне можно всё делать функционально.